# Parcel android.os.Parcel: Unmarshalling unknown type code

Tags: android, android-fragments

Here is the stack trace.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shakti.mathssolver/com.mathssolver.pstrip.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@4215dec0: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7733356 at offset 24
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@4215dec0: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7733356 at offset 24
   at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2080)
   at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2313)
   at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249)
   at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:1275)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:881)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:1912)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:266)
   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:122)
   at com.google.analyticscode.MyTrackerActivity.onCreate(MyTrackerActivity.java:21)
   at     com.google.billing.BillingHandlerLayerActivity.onCreate(BillingHandlerLayerActivity.java:36)
   at com.mathssolver.pstrip.BaseSampleActivity.onCreate(BaseSampleActivity.java:164)
   at com.mathssolver.pstrip.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:96)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Here is one of the Parcelable i am using

```
public class QuesSolnInfo implements Parcelable {

private String strValue;
private Integer intValue;

public String ques;
public String ans;
public Bitmap ans_b;

/**
 * Standard basic constructor for non-parcel
 * object creation
 */
public QuesSolnInfo() { ; }


public QuesSolnInfo(String ques, String ans, Bitmap ans_b) {
    this.ques = ques; 
    this.ans = ans;
    this.ans_b = ans_b;
}

/**
 *
 * Constructor to use when re-constructing object
 * from a parcel
 *
 * @param in a parcel from which to read this object
 */
public QuesSolnInfo(Parcel in) {
    readFromParcel(in);
}

/**
 * standard getter
 *
 * @return strValue
 */
public String getStrValue() {
    return strValue;
}

/**
 * Standard setter
 *
 * @param strValue
 */
public void setStrValue(String strValue) {
    this.strValue = strValue;
}

/**
 * standard getter
 *
 * @return
 */
public Integer getIntValue() {
    return intValue;
}

/**
 * Standard setter
 *
 * @param intValue
 */
public void setIntValue(Integer intValue) {
    this.intValue = intValue;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    if(ans_b == null || ques == null)
        return;

    // We just need to write each field into the
    // parcel. When we read from parcel, they
    // will come back in the same order
    ans_b.writeToParcel(dest, 0);
    dest.writeString(ques);
    //dest.writeString(ans);
}

/**
 *
 * Called from the constructor to create this
 * object from a parcel.
 *
 * @param in parcel from which to re-create object
 */
private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {

    // We just need to read back each
    // field in the order that it was
    // written to the parcel
    in.setDataPosition(0);

    try {
        ans_b = Bitmap.CREATOR.createFromParcel(in);
        ques = in.readString();
    } catch (Exception e) { // TODO: handle exception
        ans_b = null;
        ques = null;
    }
    //ans = in.readString();
}

/**
 *
 * This field is needed for Android to be able to
 * create new objects, individually or as arrays.
 *
 * This also means that you can use use the default
 * constructor to create the object and use another
 * method to hyrdate it as necessary.
 *
 * I just find it easier to use the constructor.
 * It makes sense for the way my brain thinks ;-)
 *
 */
public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public QuesSolnInfo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new QuesSolnInfo(in);
        }

        public QuesSolnInfo[] newArray(int size) {
            return new QuesSolnInfo[size];
        }
    };
```

}

I also have following line in my proguard file as suggested for other similar issues in other question here

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
static ** CREATOR;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Please write your parcelable class properly, i also make same mistake in parcelable class, you can refer this link also, 
[RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel: Unmarshalling unknown type code when using android bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651708/runtimeexception-parcel-android-os-parcel-unmarshalling-unknown-type-code-when/42413286#42413286)